# No puedo ver las animaciones en CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, web, animación

Estoy aprendiendo a animar en CSS.

Cuando ejecuto este código en Codepen uso este preprocesador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pero cuando quiero usar VScode con la extensión de Live server, no me funciona**, pensé que era porque no lo subía a la web, pero cuando lo hice tampoco me funcionó, luego revisando, me dijeron que le ponga `-webkit`, pero tampoco funciona.

Este es el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .circle{
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            border-radius:50%;
            background-color:red;
            border:5px solid #000;
        }

        .circle:first-child {
            -webkit-animation:circle1 1s infinite alternate;

            @-webkit-keyframes circle1{
                to{
                    width:400px;
                    height:450px;
                }
            }
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="circle">

    </div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presentas varios problemas que impiden que la animación funcione correctamente. Una animación por `@keyframes` cuenta con dos cosas:

1. La animación (el `@heyframes` propiamente dicho)
2. La clase del elemento al que quieres aplicarla, además de la propiedades que quieres darle a la animación (en tu caso `animation: circle1 1s infinite alternate`.

En tu ejemplo estás tratando de meter la definición de la animación (el `@keyframes`) dentro de una clase, debes sacarla fuera. También estás definiendo la animación en otra regla que afecta a la clase `.circulo`, puedes meterla dentro de la que definiste en primer lugar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
          .circle{
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            border-radius:50%;
            background-color:red;
            border:5px solid #000;
            animation:circle1 1s infinite alternate;
          }

          @keyframes circle1 {
              to{
                  width:400px;
                  height:450px;
              }
          }      
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="circle">

    </div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias, eso era, pero en el tutorial que estoy viendo lo hace como lo puse en el ejemplo, ¿Por qué será?

Comment: A lo mejor se trata de algo específico de SCSS, aunque estuve buscando al respecto y no encontré ningún lado donde se usaran así las animaciones.